# How to return object from recursive function?

Tags: javascript, json, object, return

I have the following function :

```
function get_(v,data) {
  var xhttp,somevar;
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  if(v!='output'){
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          if(v=='go') { 
              somevar = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText); 
              get_jurl('get',somevar);
            }
          if(v=='get') { get_jurl('output', JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]) }
        }
    }; }

  if(v=='go') {xhttp.open("GET", 'https://someurl', true)} 
  else if(v=='get') {xhttp.open("GET", 'https://otherurl', true)}
  else if(v=='output') {return data}
  xhttp.send();
}
```

It's just a pseudo-recursive function with multiple purpose. The idea is that you do a `get_('go')` call, which will reiterate to itself with a `get_('get', somevar)` call, which gets a JSON list of objects and finally reiterates to itself with a `get_('output',data)` call, which SHOULD return the `data` variable (object).

But it doesn't. If you call `get_('go')` it returns undefined, instead of the object. If you change the `return data` statement to `console.log(data)` inside the function, you'll see the object. But it doesn't work with `return` (even though return works with other variable types instead of object).

How can I make it return the object?

Comment: It works asynchronously so don't expect the answer right then.

Comment: @MinusFour , I don't think you evaluated the function correctly. It does work in tests, if I replace the `return data` with `console.log(data)`, but I want to return the value for external use on demand

Comment: When you call `get_` you schedule an action to be executed when `data` arrives. Notice you are never calling your function  passed down to `onreadystatechange`, it does so for you when the `readyState` prop changes. Meanwhile, your function keeps on going and returns `undefined`.